# (How) can I recover a lost .par file if data files are still there?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

**Main Problem**

After some critical maintenance work of one of our dev environments, we somehow lost both the `.frm` file and the `.par` file for a data-critical partitioned table (of over 1TB).

However, all actual data files are still there on the box (namely the `.ibd` files, as we are using InnoDB).

We have no backups.

The symptom is that the table seems to have disappeared from the database.

Is there a way to recover both the `.frm` and the `.par` file from the existing data files?

**Bonus Point**

After some troubleshooting I was able to copy the same `.frm` and `.par` files from a similar healthy environment (from now on I will call my broken environment env-1 and the healthy environment I copied the files from env-2).

Now, the partitions are made by time, and the problem is that the data retention policy of env-2 is set to keep way less data than env-1 (like 1 month vs 6 months worth of data).

As a result, env-2 normally has less table partitions (only for the most recent weeks) than env-1.

Therefore, while the `.frm` file is probably fine (the table definition is exactly the same), by using the `.par` file of env-2 I do now see my data, but only for the latest-week partitions. In other words, I still have a bunch of (older) data on env-1 that keep being hidden.

I thought I'd mention this just in case it would be easier to recover the `.par` file than the `.frm` file, but if there's a more proper way to recover the `.frm` file I'm all ears.